# Is there a totally 'clean' full-screen mode web browser?

Tags: fullscreen, web-browser

As the title describes, I'm looking for a totally clean full screen web browser with quick navigating options in Mac OS X.

To be specific, I don't want url bar, toolbar or anything else when in full screen mode. Although I've known that safari can hide toolbar in full screen after a few tweaks, navigating seems to be a big pain and I hate moving mouses. I'm also looking for something like sublime text's pop out input bar: with a quick gesture and some simple input, I can reach most of the functions a mouse can do in few seconds.

Does a browser like this even exists for Mac OS X?

EDIT: @dwightk has provided two feasible options in the answer below using plugins for chrome and safari. But I would like this question to remain open if anyone know more solutions

Comment: I think several browsers do this if you just hit F11...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [Vimium for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb)?

I'm not sure if there is a way to hide the toolbar in Chrome, but the [vim extension for Safari](http://www.pimpmysafari.com/items/vim-get-vi-keystrokes-in-Safari/) might be the last step you need for navigating using only the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work for me. And I figured out that 'presentation mode' of chrome can hide everything.